# read streams line by line

Tags: delphi, encoding, stream, delphi-2009

Is there a way in Delphi to read streams ,line by line?

Is there a way to set the encoding of the stream?

I know of

```
TEncoding.getEncodingPage(1250);
```

How to get it from stream?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`TStreamReader`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStreamReader). You set the encoding in the constructor and then call [`ReadLine`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStreamReader.ReadLine).

In terms of how to get the encoding from the stream, that depends very much on what is in the stream, doesn't it?

Comment: TStreamReader is available from which Delphi version?

Comment: I don't remember, but it's in D2009, which is how you tagged your question.

Comment: New link to TStreamReader documentation http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Classes.TStreamReader

Answer (score 5):

Delphi versions that lack `TStreamReader` can use [Peter Below's *StreamIO* unit](http://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.objectpascal/msg/d682a8b5a5760ac4), which gives you `AssignStream`. It works just like `AssignFile`, but for streams instead of file names. Once you've used that function to associate a stream with a `TextFile` variable, you can call `ReadLn` and the other I/O functions on it just like any other file.